# Logstash Dissect filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to upload cvs.file from logstash to elasticsearch before that I need to
to split a single cell with a different number of strings into separate cells (fields) via DISSECT FILTER
Assign the names of the fields from the string itself. If I manually write the names of the fields and their number(like in the example below), it works but in the real database there is a different number of string for each row in Category column. I need to write a universal entry in 'message' which would separate strings into separate fields regardless of their number. The names of the fields must match the value of the string in the cell.

Here is the working code:
Data

```
ID,Name,Category
1,Sofa,"Furniture,Soft furnishings,Altcategory1"
2,Desk Chair,"Furniture,Hard furnishings,Altcategory2"
```

```rb
input{
  file {
    path => "E:/test.csv"  
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NULL"
  }   
}

filter {
  dissect {
    mapping => {
      "message" => '%{product_id},%{name},"%{category},%{sub_category},%{alt_category}"'
    }
  }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "test_products5"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "**" 
  }
stdout{}
}
```

What ELK show :

```json
"_source": {
"product_id": 1,
"name": "Desk Chair",
"category": "Furniture",
"sub_category": "Hard furnishings",
"alt_category": "Altcategory2",
}

"_source": {
"product_id": 2,
"name": "Sofa",
"category": "Furniture",
"sub_category": "Soft furnishings",
"alt_category": "Altcategory1",
}
Which is correct but real data is a bit complicated that this example.
```

Real Data Example which I can't upload the way I want:

```
ID,Name,Category
1,Sofa,"Furniture,Soft furnishings, categoryE7E7163,Hendi,"
2,Desk Chair,"Furniture,Hard furnishings" - (Category column contains less strings than the row above
```

What I need to be stored in ELK

```json
"_source": {
"ID": 1,
"Name": "Desk Chair",
"Category": "Furniture",
"Hard furnishings": "Hard furnishings"
}

"_source": {
"ID": 2,
"Name": "Sofa",
"Category": "Furniture",
"Soft furnishings": "Soft furnishings",
"categoryE7E7163": "categoryE7E7163",
"Bartscher": "Bartscher",
}
```

I found ''. dot key solution'' which might help me but don't know how to implement it. It should look like this I guess:

```rb
filter {
  dissect {
    mapping => {
      "message" => '%{product_id},%{name},"%{.},%{.},%{.}%{.},%{.},%{.}"'
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't work also I don't know how to deal with different numbers of Category strings
}

Comment: Hi Alexey, so If I understand well you wan the key and the value to be the same ? I would advise against it as it will lead to mapping explosion https://www.elastic.co/blog/3-ways-to-prevent-mapping-explosion-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @Paulo Hi:) You are right! What I really needed was to divide one column into separate parts so that I could search for a specific category from a string that is in one column. Anyway, I found a solution:
```
input{
  file {
    path => "C:/100.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
  }   
}

filter {
   csv { 
 separator => ";"
    
 columns => ["Id","Name", "Category"]
 remove_field => ["message"]
 }
   mutate {
  split => { "Category" => "," }
   }
}
output{
  }
stdout{}
}
```